# Find date when value changes for each instrument

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a series of orders like below in a mongodb collection:

```
id date       value
A  1 Jan 18   1
A  2 Jan 18   0
A  3 Jan 18   0
B  14 Jan 18  4
B  15 Jan 18  5
B  16 Jan 18  0
```

Using the mongodb aggregation pipeline (mongo 3.4), I am trying to find out for each id, on what date it's value changes to 0 from non-zero, as well as the "id group" for those records.

**Second update: 26 May 19**

I have updated the question to make more clear how a first, last implementation looks like:

```
{
    "$addFields": {
      "date": {
        "$dateFromString": {
          "dateString": "$date"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "id": "$id",
        "value": "$value"
      },
      "first": {
        "$first": "$date"
      },
      "last": {
        "$last": "$date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id.value": 0
    }
  }
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/moBRI2Q7aGu

This gives me:

```
id value   first      last
A  0       2 Jan 18   3 Jan 18
B  0       16 Jan 18  16 Jan 18
```

If I look at the "first" dates, those are the dates where value first becomes 0 from non-zero.

However, I would like to see the entire "id group" of those values that become 0 from non-zero at some point in time. So:

```
id value   first      last
A  1       1 Jan 18   1 Jan 18
A  0       2 Jan 18   3 Jan 18
B  4       14 Jan 18  14 Jan 18
B  5       15 Jan 18  15 Jan 18
B  0       16 Jan 18  16 Jan 18
```

To get this, I need to access the group stage before the match of above pipeline, so https://mongoplayground.net/p/YTP-NBJtO4R, and filter this somehow with the resultset from the first aggregation pipeline. I do this in pandas via a left join on the first resultset, but this seems inelegant.

So now I have two different pipelines, which seems a bit inconvenient. Ideally the last resultset would come from a single aggregation pipeline.

Comment: can you clear up, you only want documents who went from 0 to 5 in following days? or does "0, 4, 5" also count?

Comment: i want those documents that go to 0, from a previous day of non-zero. So for id A, i would be looking for 2 Jan 18, for id B for 16 Jan 18 in my resultset.

Comment: my bad i miss read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "date": { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$date" }}
  }},
  { "$sort": { "date": 1 }},
  { "$match": { "value": 0 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$id",
    "date": { "$first": "$date" },
    "value": { "$first": "$value" }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MsD82fRQTp3)

With some more aggregation trick

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "value": "0" }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "date": { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$date" }}
  }},
  { "$sort": { "date": 1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$id",
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "value": "$value",
        "date": "$date"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "data": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$filter": {
          "input": "$data",
          "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.value", "0"] }
        }},
        0
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { "$mergeObjects": [{ "id": "$_id" }, "$data"] }
  }}
])
```

You can remove the first stage `$addFields` if your documents already contain date in Date format not the way you have shown above.

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-1kpYURP6mz)

Comment: 1. `$dateFromString` does not exists on mongo 3.4,   2. both queries are just wrong - in both you are just returning the first 0, which can be followed by another 0  no check if a positive value follows or not. also even if the first value 0 match is true you return only that one and might miss more matches.

Comment: @tomslabbaert **#1**. I belive OP just showed an example of dataset in the question not the actual data and saved the `date` as `Date` not with a `String`. I have converted the string date to date to `$sort` the data accordingly. And even if the `$dateFromString` is not exists in 3.4, it is an answer for aggregation. **#2** Your second point is baseless. OP just needs the first zeroth value (and that is why I am using `$sort` above). Also my second query is  that is what OP says in the second last para(answered before OP's update).

Comment: I'm sorry but i think you just miss read the question. he wants all the ids of documents where the field value changes from 0 to a positive number ***I am trying to find out for each id, on what date it's value changes to 0 from non-zero.***

Comment: @tomslabbaert **it's value changes to 0 from non-zero.** Keep calm and read the line again it says **changes** to 0 **from** non zero.  You missed that.

Comment: hi both, i updated the question hopefully it is now clearer.

Comment: @KaiAeberli I am still sure my answer is what you are seeking for.

Comment: @Fanpark: looking at your first answer, i get the ouput `B 16 Jan 0` and `A 2 Jan 0`. This resolves the first part of the problem. What about the second part -  I need to use the ids from this result (so A and B in this case), and show all the first, last, value combinations for each id. See my last paragraph.

Comment: @KaiAeberli Could you update the question with the updated expected output

Comment: @Fanpark: I updated the question, hope it makes more sense

Comment: @KaiAeberli Please ask a new question with proper explanation and keep the data in JSON format instead of table.

Answer (score 1):

Start off by grouping by ID so we can work on each "order" by itself:

```
{
  $group: {
     _id: "$id",
     date_x_value: {$push: {date: "$date", value: "$value"}},
     sum: {$sum: "$value"}
  }
}
```

Now match only relevant documents:

```
{
  $match: {
      $and: [ {"date_x_value.value": 0}, {sum: {$gt: 0}}]
   }
}
```

Follow by sorting by date:

```
{
  $sort: {
    "date_x_value.date": 1
  }
}
```

Now for the actual query:

```
{ $addFields:
    {
        matches: { 
            $reduce: {
               input: "$date_x_value", 
               initialValue: {"last_value": 0, "dates": []},
               in: { 
                   last_value: "$$this.value",
                   dates: { $concatArrays : [
                       {
                          $cond:{
                             if: {$and: [{$gt: ["$$value.last_value", 0]}, {$eq: ["$$this.value", 0]}]},
                             then: ["$$this.date"],
                             else: []
                          }
                      }, "$$value.dates"] 
                   }
               }
          }
       } 
    }
}
```

This will return an array of dates, note that dates are dates after the 0.
meaning for the two documents:

```
date: Jan 1,  value: 4
date: Jan 2,  value: 0
```

the array will contain Jan 2.

Edit** : note that i didn't not try to optimise the query ***at all*** i went for readability, if this is an issue you should optimise the first part before the main query according to the index's the collection has.

Comment: hi @tomslabbaert: i ran this, but it doesn't look like what i need - i was looking for the date when a value goes to zero, not to non-zero. However, this might make a useful addition - i had a look at my data, and in some edge cases it is possible to go to zero, and then after a year it will go to non-zero again.

Comment: i edited the question and is adujsted to go to a zero, run the query and see the results. its a minor change in the $cond, you will get the dates as explained in the button of my answer, if you need the dates "before" the change and not "after" this can be done with ease using [$reverseArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reverseArray/) before the main query. if you need help doing it let me know and i can re-edit my question to include it.